how to use the package name prismaticoder / maker-checker-laravel for multilevel approval in Laravel
we have multiple agencies and each agency has different  approval levels for documents. makers and checkers both are from user table having agency id and role. there are different checkers related to each agency. sometimes checkers are 2 levels, sometimes checkers are 3 levels. so its a dynamic thing. how to handle it?
I have already implemented it for single approval.

Please add the code you've tried, on SO we help you with your code, we will not tell you how to do something or write the code for you.
